# Why, after owin implementation, swagger not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm developing an RESTful web service using Microsoft Web API 2 and SwaggerUi.

I've removed default Global.asax and I've configured my Web API using OWIN. This is my Startup.cs code:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new JWTAuthenticationHandler() { StopPipelineHandling = true });

        config.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter());

        SwaggerConfig.Register();

        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
```

This is my SwaggerConfig.cs code:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyNamespace.WebApi");
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {});
```

After this operation I cannot view the actions on swagger like following images:

[image: Swagger screen without actions]

Please, can you help me?

Thank you a lot

Comment: I suggest that you use your browser developer tools (F12) to see what is returned from your web API. Most likely you are getting error status codes that you then have to fix.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've tried and I can consume my API correctly.

Comment: Try this instead of passing using "GlobalConfiguration.Configuration" pass the httpConfiguration to the swagger register.

  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableSwagger(c => {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyNamespace.WebApi");            })                .EnableSwaggerUi();}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've resolved changing:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Swagger
    SwaggerConfig.Register(config);

    // Authentication token
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    // SignalR configuration
    ConfigureSignalR(app);

    // Register routes
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    // Allow cross-domain requests
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

SwaggerConfig.cs

```
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Name.API 
{
     public class SwaggerConfig
     {
          public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
          {
                config.EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Name.API");   
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
         }
     }
}
```

I've find the solution on https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/196

Answer (score 2):

I had tons of issues with Owin + Swashbuckle integration. The solution given above is incomplete and I had to figure out many other things to ensure compatibility. My final result is open sourced in this repo, to be used as a template for anyone who needs it!

Please check: [ASPSwaggerOwinTemplate](https://github.com/jetsons/ASPSwaggerOwinTemplate)

Comment: Please elaborate which kind of issues you had.